# Comment links fail when next to non-whitespace

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, chat, markdown-rendering

#### Parens, outside

Input: ([text](http://example.com)
Result: ([text]([example.com](http://example.com))
Expected: ([text](http://example.com)

#### Brackets, inside

Input: [[text]](http://example.com)
Result:  [[text]]([example.com](http://example.com))
Expected: [[text]](http://example.com)

These issues affect chat's markdown rendering too.

Comment: Z[text](http://example.com)

Answer (score 4):

I agree on the first one. While it makes sense to put some restrictions on (e.g.) italic markup, so that

```
@UserXYZ: Are you sure that 2*3*4 is 42?
```

does the right thing, the link syntax `[bla](http://x)` is so unambiguous that the restriction really isn't necessary. This will work in the next build.

Regarding the second one: You can write anything you want into the link text, so I really don't see the point of checking for nested brackets, thereby making some kind of syntactic assumption about free text.

For the rare cases that there's a closing bracket in a link text, I think it's fine to require the user to type one extra backslash to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not only on parens, they might be expecting a whitespace before []

Comment: That would explain the behavior I've been seeing with *italic* links.  (Doesn't work with asterisks either inside or outside.)  And [tag] links, for that matter, (which I always do inside).

Answer (score 1):

Could we get this looked at? My issue was with trying to put quotes around a link:

"[text](http://example.com)" doesn't surround the link with quotes, but [[text](http://example.com)] *does* surround with brackets?

```
Another link is 
"[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)"
```

This works in an answer

Another link is "[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)"

But not in a comment (see below).

Putting the quotes in the `[text]` works, but the quotes aren't actually part of what I was trying to link. I was taught in school (ages ago) to put quotes around the title of an article I'm referring to, like "Generics (C# Programming Guide)". But in creating a link from this, I don't think I should be including the quotes.

Of course, I was taught before the Internet, so they didn't tell us what to do in this case. Just guessing.

Comment: Another link is "[Generics (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)"

Comment: Another link is ["Generics (C# Programming Guide)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Well for your second example, I always would put the brackets outside of the link.  And the following works (without leading whitespace):

`[[text](http://example.com)]`

Doesn't seem to work for parens however.  This behavior makes sense to me (considering parser design).  Though, not if the parens are actually balanced.

Comment: When used for tags, I prefer to put the backets inside; e.g. [tag].

Comment: As much is it would be convenient to be able to do that (within the link), I don't think they would be willing to change the comment parser for this.  According to NullUser's comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66472/url-detecting-error-with-address-like-http-en-wikipedia-org-wiki-octet-comput), you could probably escape the special characters using `%91` and `%93`.  [%91test%93](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52312/150562)  Nope doesn't work.

Comment: This makes “[text” a hyperlink as I reported in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66486/links-in-comments-and-square-brackets-closed.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Ah I had always thought the bracket was surrounding.  Well good to know.

Comment: "[text](http://example.com)" doesn't surround the link with quotes, but [[text](http://example.com)] _does_ surround with brackets?