# Links in comments have problems when adjacent to punctuation

Tags: bug, comments, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment links fail when next to non-whitespace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52312/comment-links-fail-when-next-to-non-whitespace)

I was trying to add a link to a comment [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3601/whose-usage-determines-correctness/3605#3605), using the `[link title](link URL)` format, but it seems to be broken next to quotation marks.

Here is the comment text I was trying to enter:

> Well, I searched for “[Luxembourgish](http://europa.eu/geninfo/query/resultaction.jsp?
>   userinput=luxembourgish)” and “[Luxembourgian]
>   (http://europa.eu/geninfo/query/resultaction.jsp?userinput=luxembourgian) ” at europa.eu 
>   and found more than a hundred examples of each, so it seems that both words are in 
>   common usage by EU bureaucrats.

Here’s what it looks like:
[image: broken comment]

I was able to get it to work by putting spaces between the link and the quotation marks, but the result still looks kinda janky:

[image: kinda fixed comment]

What gives? Are links not permitted inside quotation marks, or is this a bug?

Comment: [A working link v2](http://google.com)- "(A non working link v1)[google.com]" "[A non working link v2](http://google.com)"

Comment: Weird, there's even a `)"/` attached to the end of the last link, as well as a semicolon in text

Comment: This is a known issue (have run into it often myself), but I don't know if anyone has posted a [bug] about it yet.  I do recall seeing it mentioned in answers and comments.

Comment: I was going to recommend italics, but they don't work either: "I searched for *[Luxembourgish](http://europa.eu/geninfo/query/resultaction.jsp?userinput=luxembourgish)* ..."

Comment: Actually, someone did [post about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52312/54262)!