# URL detecting error with address like "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)"

Tags: bug, status-completed

I tried this text:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)
```

in comment. But URL detecting algorithm excluded last ")" character. This might be a bug.

Comment: This is an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)

Comment: Use `%29` instead of `)` example: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing%29)

Comment: @Popular It looks like the URL has to end in a parenthesis for this to work, as all the example links in that post are actually right (I assume the autolinking behavior was changed at some point). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx vs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)

Comment: @Michael, to be honest, I usually reference that post for the top answer, not the actual question. But see also my [sandbox entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/64463#64463); in the course of writing this reply, I discovered that the behavior I expected has changed.

Comment: Reopening this since the other post really is a mess (and I have to put my answer somewhere where it makes sense), and really only tangentially touches this issue.

Answer (score 19):

From the next build on, trailing parenetheses in auto-linked URLs (both in posts and in comments) will be included in the link if they have a matching opening parenthesis in the link. In particular this covers your case, which is the most common one.

In other words, these are linked as expected:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow_(disambiguation)

A byte or octet (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing))
```

This isn't:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/)
```

– you still have to explicitly mark the beginning and end of the link with angle brackets:

```
<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/)>
```

(or encode the parenthesis, which the editor's "link" button will do automatically for you).

Comment: Kickass, this bug made linking wikis such a pain