# Links in comments and square brackets

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

It seems that it is impossible to enclose a link in a comment by square brackets.  For example, writing `[[ABC](https://stackoverflow.com/)]` in a comment generates “[[ABC](https://stackoverflow.com/)]” instead of “[[ABC](https://stackoverflow.com/)].”  It generates the latter in a question or an answer, which is great: [[ABC](https://stackoverflow.com/)].

<del>Related to this, `[[ABC]](https://stackoverflow.com/)` is recognized as a link in a question or an answer (great again): [[ABC]](https://stackoverflow.com/), but not in a comment.</del>

It would be nice if these work in comments in the same way as in questions and answers.  For example, I wanted to use either of these forms in the first comment to [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/complexity-of-exponential-function/1819#1819) on the Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exhange site.

*Edit*: As Jared Harley stated in a comment, the second issue had been already reported in “[Comment links fail when next to non-whitespace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52312/comment-links-fail-when-next-to-non-whitespace).”

Comment: Here are demonstrations of the issues.  The first issue: [[ABC](http://stackoverflow.com/)].  The second issue: [[ABC]](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Jared Harley: Thank you for the information.  That page covers the second issue.  I removed the second issue from the request.